# After an AJAX DELETE request how can I redirect to a provided URI?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, get, http-delete

I have the following AJAX call...

```
remove() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.deleteUri,
        type: `DELETE`,
        contentType: `application/json; charset=utf-8`,
        cache: false,
        success: () => {
            if (this.successUri) { UrlHelper.go(this.successUri); }
        },
        error: (xhr, status) => {
            this.showFailed();
        }
    });
}
```

UrlHelper.go is simply wrapping location.href as follows...

```
UrlHelper.go = function (url) {
    location.href = url;
};
```

When the success callback is fired the problem that I have is that the success URL is being called using a DELETE verb although this is not what I want. Is there something I'm missing to make this a GET?

NOTE: This is using arrow functions and ES6 calls.

The issue is that the URL in this.successUri is called using an Http DELETE verb and not an Http GET verb. As it is a redirect I need to call it with Http GET. There is nothing at that URL that responds to an Http DELETE verb.

Here's the whole component this is part of...

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/bootbox/bootbox.js" />

import Guard from "../helpers/guard";
import UrlHelper from "../helpers/url-helper";

export default class DeleteButton {

    /**
     * Creates an instance of DeleteButton.
     * 
     * @param {object} element The DOM element to make into a delete button.
     * 
     * @memberOf DeleteButton
     */
    constructor(element) {
        Guard.throwIf(element, "element");

        this.deleteUri = element.getAttribute("data-delete-uri") || UrlHelper.current.url().split('?')[0];        
        this.title = element.getAttribute("data-title") || `Delete the item?`;
        this.cancelText = element.getAttribute("data-cancel") || `Cancel`;
        this.confirmText = element.getAttribute("data-confirm") || `Remove`;
        this.message = element.getAttribute("data-message") || `Do you want to delete the item? This cannot be undone.`;
        this.successUri = element.getAttribute("data-success-uri");
        this.errorMessage = element.getAttribute("data-error-message") || `Unable to complete operation.`;

        $(element).click(this.confirmRemove.bind(this));
    }

    /**
     * Confirms deletion of an item.
     * 
     * @memberOf DeleteButton
     */
    confirmRemove() {
        window.bootbox.confirm({
            title: this.title,
            message: this.message,
            buttons: {
                cancel: {
                    label: `<i class=\"fa fa-times\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>${this.cancelText}`
                },
                confirm: {
                    className: `btn-danger`,
                    label: `<i class=\"fa fa-check\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>${this.confirmText}`
                }
            },
            callback: (result) => {
                if (result) { this.remove(); }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Removes an item from the server.
     *
     * @memberOf DeleteButton
     */
    remove() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.deleteUri,
            type: `DELETE`,
            contentType: `application/json; charset=utf-8`,
            cache: false,
            success: () => {
                if (this.successUri) { UrlHelper.go(this.successUri); }
            },
            error: (xhr, status) => {
                this.showFailed();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Shows failure of deletion.
     * 
     * @memberOf DeleteButton
     */
    showFailed() {
        window.bootbox.alert({
            message: this.errorMessage,
            size: `small`,
            backdrop: true
        });
    }
}
```

and it's linked to the following HTML...

```
    <a class="js-delete-button btn btn-danger" data-id="@Model.ID" data-title="Stop the Route?" data-confirm="Stop Route" data-success-uri="/routes"
        data-message="Do you want to stop running this route? Routes with no journeys will be permanently deleted. This cannot be undone."><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i>Stop Running</a>
```

Which, after the delete operation succeeds, is then generating the following request...

```
:authority:localhost:44333
:method:DELETE
:path:/Routes?Message=The%20route%20requested%20has%20been%20stopped.
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
accept-language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
cache-control:no-cache
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
origin:https://localhost:44333
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://localhost:44333/Route/30005?Message=A%20new%20route%20has%20been%20created.%20Now%20download%20and%20complete%20the%20Timetable%20template%20to%20configure%20all%20of%20the%20stops%20and%20journey%20times.
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: So why are you using DELETE if you need GET?

Comment: The AJAX call deletes a record from the database. If the deletion succeeds I need to redirect the browser to the list page.

Comment: Are you sure `this` is what you are expecting within `success`? `this` is `jqXHR` object by default within `success` of `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: Yes - within an arrow function 'this' is resolved differently. The values coming back within the callback are fine. If I remove the arrow functions and use .bind(this) instead then (in this case) I get the same result.

Comment: _"The values coming back within the callback are fine."_ Not sure what issue is? Does server support `DELETE`? Is `if (this.successUri) { UrlHelper.go(this.successUri); }` not being called?

Comment: The issue is that the URL in this.successUri is called using an Http DELETE verb and not an Http GET verb. As it is a redirect I need to call it with Http GET. There is nothing at that URL that responds to an Http DELETE verb.

Comment: What is `this.successUri`?

Comment: https://localhost:44333/Routes - It exists on the server for GET but not for DELETE (that wouldn't make sense)

Comment: Are you conveying that `location.href` is making a `DELETE` request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136384/discussion-between-keith-jackson-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a client side problem but a server redirection issue due to a bad method call. With a lot of help from responders I was able to determine that the success callback wasn't actually firing - the server was trying to do something else.